# Xcode 4.2 UITableView with editable login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, ios5

Is anyone familiar with a tutorial out there that will let me create a UITableView Login EXACTLY like how on iOS 5 Settings -> Twitter -> Add Account.

The tutorials I have seen show a textfield ontop of the tablecell which makes the textfield obvious. I would like it to be non obvious just like the twitter app built into iOS5 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the UITextField's borderStyle to UITextFieldBorderStyleNone? What is it about the text field that is 'obvious'? Not knowing which tutorials you have follow, if you can describe the difference between your current implementation and what you want, it will be easier to help your further.

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up doing was setting the border to none so it didn't look like a text field was just overlayed ontop.

Comment: Great! I must admit I was a little confused, as the docs say that None is the default border, and after looking at the twitter app settings I was like 'textfield ontop of cell... What's the problem?'glad this helped you resolve it!